# Can't resolve 'react-transition-group' in primereact dropdown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, primereact

I am getting the following error-

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/primereact/components/dropdown/DropdownPanel.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-transition-group' in 'D:\my-app\node_modules\primereact\components\dropdown'
```

This is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
"primeflex": "^2.0.0",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primereact": "^6.1.0",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
},
```

In App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown'; //getting error after adding this line
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css';
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you compiling with? What's the compile command?

Comment: @aryzing after adding "import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown';"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Could it be that you only included the types, `"@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",`, but did not install the actual package?

Try installing the package with `npm install react-transition-group`. The `@types/*` repo only contains types, not code.

Comment: I used "npm install @types/react-transition-group"

Comment: try `npm install react-transition-group`